# Why is content-length required in case of HTTP persistent connections

Tags: http, tcp, client-server, persistent-connection

My understanding of how data transfer happens in tcp/http is this:

The application layer on the server side passes some data to the tcp layer to be sent to the client. The tcp layer breaks the application data into segments and sends it further. The tcp layer on the other end will ensure that it receives and arranges all the segments in order before passing them to its application layer.

Now, `in the case of non-persistent connections`, the server can simply close the connection when it is done sending data. What does this mean? Does it mean the server will send a `FIN` segment at the end? So, the client's tcp layer will basically wait for all the segments upto the FIN segment, pass this data to the upper layers and proceed with connection termination.

`In the case of persistent connections`, as the connection is not closed by the server, it is said that the client cannot know when it has to finish reading the response and do the next request. And so the `content-length` header and `chunked transfer` are used.

My question is "**why can't we just send a segment similar to FIN (say DONE) to indicate that the server has transmitted all the response**". The client on seeing DONE can start with the next request. What was the need to include a content-length header which comes with the issue of knowing the content length in advance?

I am sure I have misunderstood or missed something here. Please correct me where I am wrong above.

Thanks for reading upto here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine what would happen if your HTTP-payload data contained `DONE` in its middle.

TCP `FIN` packets on the other hand mark the `FIN` within the TCP header's flags and thus, there is no danger of errorneously mistaking some data packet as a `FIN` packet.

Comment: Thanks, I got the point now. May be we could have used one of the reserved bits to mark `DONE`.

Comment: No, we could not have used any of the reserved (TCP-)bits to mark `DONE` since TCP is at the transport level, while HTTP is at the application level (OSI model). This especially means that all of the HTTP specific stuff must be contained within the payload area of the TCP packets.

Answer (score 1):

Because DONE might occur in the body of the response, as there is no escape mechanism specified in the protocol.

Comment: ok, so how is FIN handled. Is there an escape mechanism for it. If so, wouldn't it have been easier to specify an escape mechanism then using content-length.

Comment: FIN is out of band: a bit in the TCP Packet header. Not in the content. It was already too late to specify an escape mechanism, and the idea of forcing all implementations to parse all content looking for a possibly non-existent end marker doesn't exactly appeal.